# Block-wise and row-wise shuffling in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to shuffle the rows of a result set block-wise in mySQL?

To illustrate: the desired query would return the following four rows randomly in one of four possible orders (but not other possible ones, e.g. item 4 should never precede item 3).

#### original order, A before B, item1 before item2

```
item,   b_order,    i_order
item1,  A,          1
item2,  A,          1
item3,  B,          1
item4,  B,          2
```

#### A before B, item2 before item1

```
item2,  A,          1
item1,  A,          1
item3,  B,          1
item4,  B,          2
```

#### B before A, item2 before item1

```
item3,  B,          1
item4,  B,          2
item2,  A,          1
item1,  A,          1
```

#### B before A, item1 and item2 did not swap

```
item3,  B,          1
item4,  B,          2
item1,  A,          1
item2,  A,          1
```

I imagine that there might be a somewhat elegant way to solve this, by using

```
 SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY random_number_for_each_block, i_order, RAND()
```

I haven't figured out how I can generate this "random_number_for_each_block" variable.

Comment: What is your question?  You have three different result sets, but I don't understand what you are trying to do.  Write one query to return all three?  Specify parameters to get one or another?

Comment: @GordonLinoff My goal is to write one query that randomly returns one of the four enumerated result sets. Of course in the real situation these block-random, row-random experimental designs are arbitrarily complex. I tried to clarify the question.

Comment: You lost me at 'original order'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we have

```
CREATE TABLE `origin` (
  `item` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_order` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `i_order` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

You can do this with:

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  @b_rand  := IF(b_order!=@current, FLOOR(1000*RAND()), @b_rand) AS factor,
  @current := b_order AS current, 
  @b_rand + RAND() AS ordinal
FROM
  (SELECT *
   FROM origin
   ORDER BY b_order) AS ordered
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT @b_rand:=FLOOR(1000*RAND())) AS init
ORDER BY ordinal
```

Sub-query for ordering items by blocks won't be needed if you already know that in initial state they are following in groups by `b_order`. But it's safer to have it.

Check the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d27829/1) (blocks are grouped, but blocks order is random; items inside blocks are ordered randomly)

Comment: Thanks. I added the data to the SQL query to make it more easily testable. Unfortunately your solution does not work, it just shuffles completely randomly. The reason: The factor variable contains the same random number for each row/block. Also, the line with "current" seems to be superfluous?

Comment: It works correctly for me, I will try to prepare a fiddle. `@current` isn't redundant, it's needed to determine block border so whether it's required to update the factor

Comment: That's odd! Your fiddle does the block shuffling. I now also see the need for `current`. I use MySQL 5.62 on my Mac (was testing via PHPmyadmin), but it doesn't work (i.e. factor is always the same number). In the fiddle, the items are not shuffled as I wanted in blocks (probably I was unclear about this), but I could [fix that](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6b17/3/0) myself (unless you think there's a problem with my fix).

Comment: In my fiddle order of items inside block is random. Either I do not understand what's wrong or requirements are not clear

Comment: Yes, the requirements were not clear, sorry. If you see my fiddle, I think it will be clearer: I want items shuffled by block, then inside the block sorted by i_order and if that is identical (i.e. item1 and item2), shuffled within the block. Item 4 should always follow item 3. The 4 result sets in my question are really the only possible ones I want.

Comment: Thanks for undeleting. I had trouble with the sorting only when using phpmyadmin for testing. I don't know why that is (maybe something about calling `RAND()` twice), but I'm not enthusiastic to find out since this is not how I want to use it.